# JIRA: large numbers of versions

Tags: jira

JIRA has built in version information, which looks quite handy.

However, in an iterative model you might release a new version every couple of weeks and that would mean a lot of versions in the lists... which is functional but strikes me as a bit clumsy.

Is this the right way, or are there better approaches in how versions are used in JIRA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JIRA lets you ["archive" old versions](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Versions#ManagingVersions-Archivingaversion), so they stop cluttering up the interface.

Answer (score 1):

But if you have hundreds of values for any drop-down list, they are hard to navigate. One option is to use a text field. Or GreenHopper lets you have hierarchical versions. I presented yet another idea at the SF Atlassian User Group earlier this year: create a new issue type "build" and link the instances of build together. More details at:

http://toolsmiths.blogspot.com/2010/04/one-bug-multiple-branches.html